# Figuring out Windows SDK used by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, windows-installer, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-sdk

I have multiple versions of Windows Software Development Kit installed on my machine which funnily enough the one that has been installed on my machine by `Visual studio Installer` tool has lower version than the one installed almost a year ago :

```
Windows Software Development Kit => Product version 10.1.18362.1  , installed on 29/08/2019

Windows Software Development Kit => Product version 10.0.17763.132  , installed on 14/01/2020
```

How can I figure out which version of Windows SDK is currently in use by my "Visual Studio Enterprise 2019" with all the updates as of 09-June-2020?

Comment: In VS2017, right clicking a C++ project allows you to select *"Retarget projects"*. In there you can change the SDK version used. Not sure about the [C# details](https://github.com/microsoft/WinObjC/wiki/Changing-the-SDK-Version-of-a-Project). You can obviously set the .NET framework version in the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a C++ project, the Windows SDK Version dropdown in the General Properties of the project shows the list of available SDK versions, and the currently selected one.

[image]

More detailed information is available in the VC++ Directories / Include Directories / Edit box.

[image]

Similar information is available for Library Directories, too, and it can also be found directly under Macros (only it's not formatted as conveniently there).